# Spring boot jpa / hibernate wrong column type encounter (json field)

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm working on mapping a table into POJO using spring boot, and i'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mercadolibre/linters/db/config/DbaConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [linter_summary] in table [result]; found [json (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

the field `linter_summary` in the db is of type JSON and on my pojo is a String. I'm not understanding why it's making this error, is there a special variable in java for JSON fields?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.hypersistence/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55</artifactId>
    <version>${hypersistence-utils.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Next, add this annotation to the entity class:

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
```

Then add this to the column definition:

```
@Type( type = "json" )
@Column( columnDefinition = "json" )
```

where `@Type` is `org.hibernate.annotations.Type`

For explanations see [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/)

Comment: Hi Eugen, but im getting org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [json]

Comment: @elcharrua No, you can simply use `@Lob` for `longtext`.

Comment: Thanks very much Eugen

Comment: Hi after doing this, I get an error Cannot resolve symbol 'JsonStringType' and Cannot resolve symbol 'JsonBinaryType'

Comment: I am also getting same error. JsonStringType and JsonBinaryType can't resolved.

Comment: If `JsonStringType` is not resolved very likely there is an issue with dependency. Make sure you've provided version number and reimport project in your IDE

Comment: @ruX Can you please specify what is the version number you mean? I get a similar error -`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonType` only when I upgrade my spring version to 5.3.18. The vladmihalcea dependency is already present and working. The error surfaced as I upgraded my spring version.

Comment: @Ela it does look like it can't find the class in the classpath. But I'd inspect the whole stacktrace - maybe class can't be loaded for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases if you're not building a web server container, try adding

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This helps to provide some of the serialization features that you may need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).